# Moodle and Google SSO

Tags: moodle, google-sso

My school is looking to use moodle as an LMS and integrating it with google apps. What I would like to implement in the integration is a single sign on where once a user is logged into google apps, they would immediately be logged into their moodle account. I want this to also be possible vice versa where a user would also be automatically logged into their google apps account if they login to moodle instead. So far the plugins I have found can only do one or the other; not both (or perhaps I do not know how to configure them this way).

I have tried using googleoauth2 and GSAML but had no luck. Can someone please help or guide me somewhere that has this implemented?

Thanks you

Comment: Which version of Moodle is it? And do you have any error messages from the plugins you tried?

Comment: I am using the latest stable version of Moodle (v2.9.1+). Googleoauth2 is working fine but it lacks the ability for users to automatically log into google apps when logged into moodle. I have also followed the instructions to setup the GSAML plugin however, when I try to login through google apps, the page is redirected and I receive a 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

THe process is well-documented here: https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Google_Apps_Integration

The [OneLogin plugin](https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=auth_onelogin_saml) (among other options) supports both SSO and Google Apps. I would suggest starting there.

The exact documentation (should you choose to proceed with this login) can be found [here](http://www.appsedudemo.com/home/simple-sign-on/adapting-existing-system-to-connect-to-openam-via-saml-using-onelogin-developed-client). You will need [OpenAM](https://www.forgerock.com/products/access-management/) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried using the OneLogin plugin but I get a blank screen when I try to configure it through Site administration > plugins > authentication > manage authentication. I am running moodle 2.9.1+.

Comment: Never mind I fixed it! However OneLogin is not free. The school would prefer a free alternative